# LIKE expression does not work a query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to search the records that have 3 or more '#'.

In MSAccess I can Write this and show me the results:

```
SELECT * FROM AlmLotes WHERE Lote LIKE '[#][#][#]*';
```

But in C# don't works.

```
DataTable dtResultats = new DataTable();

string strConnectionSource = MYCONNECTIONSTRING

OleDbConnection connAccess = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionSource);
connAccess.Open();

string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AlmLotes WHERE Lote LIKE '[#][#][#]*'";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connAccess);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
dtResultats = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResultats);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dtResultats.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var rows = dtResultats.Rows[i];
        for (int z = 0; z < dtResultats.Columns.Count; z++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dtResultats.Columns[z].ColumnName + ": " + rows[z] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
Console.ReadKey();
```

The SQL Query in MSAcces show me 5 results.
THE SQL QUery in C# show me 0 results.

Comment: Other Query's in this code works perfectly.

Comment: Does the field you are query has only `[#][#][#]*` or it has something else?

Comment: @Rekcs The fields that I want to query are like: ##########

Comment: Please post a solution as an answer not as an update to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM AlmLotes WHERE Lote LIKE LIKE '[[#]%'";
```

Comment: The same, 0 results. But if I do with normal characters or numbers It works, I think that C# don't understand the Square Brackets []

Comment: Why you are using Square Brackets and instead you only use ####

Comment: Because de Brackets meaning is that i want to search de SHARP literally, and in MS Access Works

Comment: Let me now if it actually worked. I've updated it @Tr3ndiX

Comment: You should mark the question as answered to let other people know @Tr3ndiX

Answer (score 0):

So Ms Access use `*`, but C# OleDb use `%`. You can replace `*` to `%`.

```
string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM AlmLotes WHERE Lote LIKE '###%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution are the Parameters:

```
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AlmLotes WHERE Lote LIKE @PARAM1";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connAccess);
        OleDbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
        param.ParameterName = "PARAM1";
        param.Value = "###%";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        dtResultats = new DataTable();
```